# How to trigger an element by id? (".click();" doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, text, triggers, click, event-listener

I want to trigger this element in Google Translate, so that it would always auto-correct everything I type. 
https://i.snag.gy/NRsWFB.jpg

The element's id is "spelling-correction".
I tried this:

```
document.getElementById('spelling-correction').click();
```

And this:

```
function clickLink(link) {
    var cancelled = false;

    if (document.createEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            false, false, false, false,
            0, null);
        cancelled = !link.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    else if (link.fireEvent) {
        cancelled = !link.fireEvent("onclick");
    }

    if (!cancelled) {
        window.location = link.href;
    }
}

setInterval(function copyText() {
var correction123 = document.getElementById("spelling-correction");
correction123.clickLink();
 }, 100);
```

But they don't work unfortunately. I would like to somehow trigger this "spelling-correction", so that whatever I write would be auto-corrected.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried doing that on the anchor tag inside that element, as it looks like that is what the event would be set on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you're clicking on a `div`. Divs do nothing when clicked (unless otherwise specified).

Since what you want seems to be clicking on the *link* itself, you should try something like this instead:

```
childAnchors = document.querySelectorAll("#spelling-correction > a");
childAnchors[0].click();
```